# trick of python logical operator '' or ''?

Tags: python, operators

I am learning python and have problem with logical operator 'or'. Can't find information and understand why code in various writing interpreted differently (what the difference in #First and #Second examples). So, #First example doesn't equal #Second, when operator 'and' equal in all variants of code

```
# First
a=35
b=35
if a or b>35:
    print('First')

'''with code like above python have printed 'First' even if statement false, like i understand it. 
But in other examples, statement are false too, and 'print' wasn't done, like it must be.'''

# Second
c=35
d=35
if c>35 or d>35:
    print('Second')

#Third    
e=35
f=35
if e>35 and f>35:
    print('Third')

#Fourth    
g=35
h=35
if g and h>35:
    print('Fourth')
```

Comment: Please take look at [python's operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: You need to specify the condition for both of the conditions so instead of `if a or b>35:` it would be `if a >35or b>35:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a number X directly in a condition, Python implicitely converts it to a boolean value by applying the comparison `X != 0`

So, for your examples:

## First

```
a=35
b=35
if a or b>35:        # same as if a!=0 or b>35:   True or False --> True
    print('First')
```

## Second

```
c=35
d=35
if c>35 or d>35:     # False or False --> False
    print('Second')
```

## Third

```
e=35
f=35
if e>35 and f>35:    # False and False --> False
    print('Third')
```

## Fourth

```
g=35
h=35
if g and h>35:       # same as if g!=0 and h>35:  True and False --> False
    print('Fourth')
```

If you're looking to express a condition to test that either `a` or `b` are greater than 35, you cannot write it as `a or b > 35`.
While it may be clear to you in English, it is not how Python reads it.

Python requires that you be more explicit, so you will have to repeat the `> 35` :

`a > 35 or b > 35`.

If you want to avoid repeating the 35, here's a trick you could use:

```
if max(a,b) > 35:  
   # either a or b is > 35  (i.e. the highest of the two is > 35)

if min(a,b) > 35:
   # both a and b are > 35  (i.e. the lowest of the two is > 35)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a or b > 35
```

is equivalent to

```
a or (b > 35)
```

and `a` is truthy because all integers except `0` are truthy. You can verify:

```
>>> a or b > 35
35
>>> (a or b) > 35  
False
```

See [truth testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) and [operator precedence](https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html).

Also note that `(a or b) > 35` will **not** become `True` if any of `a` or `b` is greater than `35`.

```
(a or b or c or ... or n) > 35
```

is true only if the **first non-zero number** in the disjunction is greater than `35`

Answer (score 2):

"if a" will always evaluate to true for an int if a != 0.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to split it to better understand it.
Let's take the first case:

```
a=35
b=35
if a or b>35:
  print('First')
```

In this case, your if-condition is composed of two parts `a` and `b>25`, and the `or` operator means you need at least one of them to be `True` to print `First`.

So what does `if a` means? actually that means if a is equal to a value different than `None`, `0`, `""` and `False`. So in your case, a is equal 35 thus the evaluation of the first part is `True`. The second part is evaluated to `False` since b is not greater than 35. And this is why it prints `First`.

For the fourth example, you need both of them to be evaluated True to have the print statement executed.

I hope this helps you to better understand it.